# How to show Jquery UI datepicker year and months in extra calendar tables?

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

My problem is that Jquery UI allows selecting a year or month from dropdown menu only.

How can I modify the default date picker to allow selecting year and month as additional calendar tables for default date picker?

**Default view:**

[image: default date picker: days in calendar + month and year dropdowns]

**How I want to select months -> clicking on a month to show extra calendar:**

1. Desired month functionality:

   - clickable month label
   - no dropdowns
   - when clicking on month label - it should open now calendar where days are replaced with month selection

[image: screen 1]

[image: screen 2]

*(screen 2 shows what happens when you click on target area on screen 1)*

**How I want to select years -> clicking on year to show extra calendar:**

2. Desired year functionality:

   - clickable year label
   - no dropdowns
   - when clicking on year label - it should open now calendar where days are replaced with year selection

[image: screen 1]

[image: screen 2]

*(screen 2 shows what happens when you click on target area on screen 1)*

As I understand, I need to create a new calendars onclick of "month" or "year" label but I don't have any idea how to make that + how to show months or years in calendar instead of a dropdown.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I am going to inline your images (that works easily with copy/paste). That would make your question a lot easier to read and comprehend.

Comment: This will be no easy task. If someone wants to develop this, it will propbally be done in the Widget Factory since there is no extension to modify the Month / Year rendering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to the dynamic nature of Datepicker, it rebuilds each calendar, there is not a good way to do this "out of the box".

> How can I modify the default date picker to allow selecting year and month as additional calendar tables for default date picker?

Here is a basic example of how you could start to set this up. The issue comes in when you then make a selection. The datepicker redraws all the various elements and will remove all the customization.

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/v6c9r8pa/56/

**JavaScript**

```
$(function() {
  var dp = $("#datepicker-1").datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true
  });
  $("#datepicker-2").datepicker();
  $(".ui-datepicker-month", dp).hide();
  $("<span>", {
    class: "ui-datepicker-month-btn btn"
  }).html($(".ui-datepicker-month option:selected", dp).text()).insertAfter($(".ui-datepicker-month", dp));
  $(".ui-datepicker-year", dp).hide();
  $("<span>", {
    class: "ui-datepicker-year-btn btn"
  }).html($(".ui-datepicker-year option:selected", dp).text()).insertAfter($(".ui-datepicker-year", dp));

  function selectMonth(ev) {
    var mObj = $(ev.target);
    $(".ui-datepicker-month", dp).val(mObj.data("value")).trigger("change");
    $(".ui-datepicker-month-btn", dp).html(mObj.text().trim());
    mObj.closest(".ui-datepicker").find(".ui-datepicker-calendar").show();
    mObj.closest(".ui-datepicker-month-calendar").remove();
  }

  function showMonths(trg) {
    $(".ui-datepicker-calendar", trg).hide();
    var mCal = $("<table>", {
      class: "ui-datepicker-month-calendar"
    }).insertAfter($(".ui-datepicker-calendar", trg));
    var row, cell;
    $(".ui-datepicker-month option").each(function(i, o) {
      if (i % 4 == 0) {
        row = $("<tr>").appendTo(mCal);
      }
      cell = $("<td>").appendTo(row);
      $("<span>", {
          class: "ui-widget-header circle btn"
        })
        .data("value", $(o).val())
        .html($(o).text().trim())
        .click(selectMonth)
        .appendTo(cell);
      if ($(o).is(":selected")) {
        $("span", cell).addClass("selected");
      }
    });
  }

  $(".ui-datepicker-month-btn").click(function() {
    console.log("Show Months");
    showMonths(dp);
  })
});
```

If you want to get in "under the hood", then take some time to review the following, [Widget Factory](https://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/widget-factory/).

> The jQuery UI Widget Factory is an extensible base on which all of jQuery UI's widgets are built. Using the widget factory to build a plugin provides conveniences for state management, as well as conventions for common tasks like exposing plugin methods and changing options after instantiation.

So you could rebuild some of the elements in your own making from inside, so that when you do make a selection, it redraws all the elements as you desire.